# Есть ли возможность типизировать ошибки чтобы понять, какие ошибки возвращает конкретная функция?

Tags: golang

Понимаю, что для большинства GO-разработчиков, которые занимаются микросервисами, достаточно просто того факта, что ошибка произошла. Её просто надо вернуть.

Но в моём случае этого факта недостаточно.
Дело в том, что я переписываю проект из C++, в котором в качестве результата работы функции был какой-нибудь enum:

```
enum class AuthResult { Success, IncorrectCredentials, TooManyLoginFailures, и т. д }
```

Каждая функция возвращает какой-то enum, и некоторые из них нужно обязательно обработать.

Взялся я переписывать эти функции в GO и что я вижу? Мы все ошибки фигачим сразу в пакет - "Ошибка свободна - используйте кто хотите".

> Если, например, мне необходимо обработать все ошибки, который вернул
> какой-то метод, то как мне это сделать? Как мне понять, что какая-то
> ошибка из пакета относится именно к этой функции, не читая исходный
> код функции чтобы найти все return'ы?

Неужели использовать какоё-нибудь префикс-именование, типа такого:

```
var (
    AuthError_IncorrectCredentials = errors.New("AuthError_IncorrectCredentials")
    AuthError_TooManyLoginFailures = errors.New("AuthError_TooManyLoginFailures")

    ProcessError_UserHasNoPrivilege = errors.New("ProcessError_UserHasNoPrivilege")
    ProcessError_UseIsBanned = errors.New("ProcessError_UseIsBanned")
)
```

Есть у меня вариант с разными названиями пакетов, но как тогда получать доступ к приватным полям пакетов? Что-то типа дружественных классов из С++.

Я новичок в GoLang, и что-то у вас всё сложно в этом языке.

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, решение моей проблемы.

Comment: попробуйте писать, употребляя более красивую лексику. А также, Ваши ошибки очень похожи на ошибки http.

Comment: Но если хочется знать, какая именно функция возвратила ошибку, то может просто закодировать это в отдельной переменной (поле структуры)?

Answer (score 0):

Есть два способа понять, что за ошибку вернула функция:

- сравнить значение ошиибки с константой,
- проверить, что ошибка является структурой определённого типа.

Часто этого достаточно.

Перечислить типы ошибок, которые вернёт ваша функция нельзя, вы можете указать только общий интерфейс. Но вы можете создать свою реализацию ошибки и получить что-то вроде enum из вашего примера.

```
const (
    IncorrectCredentials = iota
    TooManyLoginFailures
)

type AuthErr struct {
    msg string
    Code int
}

func (e *AuthErr) Error() string {
    return e.msg
}
```

Потом просто проверяете код ошибки и обрабатываете её как надо.